# ng-repeat without creating tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to dynamically generate a rather boring `<option>` list of times for a `<select>`,

```
<select>
  <option>8:00am</option>
  <option>8:15am</option>
  <option>8:30am</option>
  <option>8:45am</option>
  <option>9:00am</option>
  <option>9:15am</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <option>5:00pm</option>
</select>
```

I know how to generate the minutes, i.e.

```
<option ng-repeat="minutes in ['00', 15, 30, 45]">8:{{minutes}}am</option>
```

Obviously we need another loop for hours, but this would create a set of extra tags around every four `<option>`s, which would break the `<select>`.

How can one [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) without creating any tags?

Comment: Which are the tags that you don't need around <option> ?

Comment: Or how should a valid output look like?

Comment: @Catalin: The output is already there - I don't want any extra tags. Obviously we need two loops, and the outer one, for the hours, would create a set of extra tags around every four `<option>`s, which would break the `<select>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="h_m in [] track by $index | time:8:20:15">{{h_m}}</option>
</select>
```

AngularJS filter:

```
angular.filter('time', function() {
    return function(input, from, to, interval) {
        from     = parseInt(from, 10);
        to       = parseInt(to, 10);
        interval = parseInt(interval, 10);

        for(var i=from, y=0; i<=to; ++i, y+=interval) {
            for(var y=0; y<60; y+=interval) {
                input.push(((i % 12) || 12)+ ":" + (y===0?'00':y) +" " + (i>12?'pm':'am'));
            }
        }

        return input;
    };
});
```

You can set the start hour, the end hour and the interval:

`time`**:**`start_hour`**:**`end_hour`**:**`interval`

`start_hour` and `end_hour` must be in 24 time format

`interval` is in minutes and should be between 1 and 59..

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/catalinmunteanu/r1qbfcr7/).

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you. It's great for this particular problem, and the moral is that there's no way to have an "empty tag" `ng-repeat` akin to `{{#each}}...{{/each}}` in [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists).

Answer (score 0):

some boring answer with expensive memory allocation:
try something like this, you need to increase your array...

! warning, you do not want to try this one ! =)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      // from 10/13/2014 0:0:0 gmt  = 1413129600
      // to 10/13/2014 24:59:59 gmt = 1413219599
      // 1413219599 - 1413129600 = 89999
      angular.module("ng").run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.array = new Array(89999).join('0').split('');

      })

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
      <select>
          <option ng-repeat="n in array track by $index">{{1413129600+$index | date:"hh:mm:ss"}}</option>
      </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a fun solution, but besides the CPU and RAM consumption and illegibility :), it doesn't appear to work as intended... I see "12:32:09" repeated like 50 times, then "12:32:10" repeated many times etc.

Comment: ahh right, because of the milliseconds... hmmm we need to add something in between -- right it was fun =)

Answer (score 0):

please check it (Simple javascript and angularjs)

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
<select>
<option ng-repeat="dt in date">{{dt}}</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.date=["0:00am"];
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
{

for(j=1;j<5;j++)
{

if(j==4)
{
  i++;
 if(i<12)
 {
  $scope.date.push(i+":"+"00"+"am");
 }
 else
 {
      if(i==24)
     {
     }
    else
   {
    $scope.date.push(i+":"+"00"+"pm");
   }

 }
  i--;

 }
else
{
if(i<12)
{
$scope.date.push(i+":"+j*15+"am");
}
 else
{
 $scope.date.push(i+":"+j*15+"pm");
}
 }
}
}
 });
 </script>
 </body>
```